# Call C# function on cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've started learning asp.net these days and i'm trying to call a C# function on cshtml file.

ToDoList.cshtml:

```
function submitClick() {
  const checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox").checked;
  const title = document.getElementById("taskTitle").textContent;

  @Model.newTaskChecked = checkbox.checked;
  @Model.newTaskTitle = title.textContent;
  @Model.addTask();
}
```

ToDoList.cshtml.cs:

```
public void addTask()
{
  tasks.Add(this.newTaskTitle, this.newTaskChecked);
}
```

The compiler is saying that Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "void" em "object".
What do i have to do to make it work?

Comment: Welcome Ruhtra.. you can call c# from your cshtml, but you will have to put **using** for the namespace that contains your function addTask(). So put your AddTask as a static method in a public class, in a namespace.. and* refer* that namespace in your cshtml.

Comment: Did you read the tag info about asp.net? This doesn't seem about the old asp-net tech. Are you using asp.net core with razor pages ?

Comment: @Steve Yes, I am using razor pages.

Comment: @Goodies how would I do that?

Comment: You cannot call a C# method from JavaScript. JavaScript is executed on the client and  C# is executed on the server.

Comment: cshtml in Razor is NOT javascript. I have put an answer,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, please forget cshtml.cs and things like that. This is Razor MVC, so you will have a cshtml with mixed html and c#

From the c# you can use any c# in your project, when it is declared public.

Suppose you have some Class1.cs (in your project) containing a method function MyTask that looks like this..

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   public class Class1
   {
      public static bool MyTask(int x)
      { return x == 0; }
    }
}
```

.. then in your.cshtml you can put a using MyNamespace, OR you can refer to MyTask with its full name. Maybe that is easier to explain. You could use it to test and put something in the HTML, like:

```
 @if (MyNamespace.Class1.MyTask(1))
 {
   <b>ok</b>
 } 
 else
 {
   <b>nono need 0</b>
 }
```

This will say "nono need 0" in the browser.

EDIT: you can't expect to let this function work as intended:

```
 function submitClick() {
   const checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox").checked;
   const title = document.getElementById("taskTitle").textContent;

   @Model.newTaskChecked = checkbox.checked;
   @Model.newTaskTitle = title.textContent;
   @Model.addTask();
 }
```

Here you try to assign things to your model directly, from Javascript. The checkbox.checked is unknown at the server side. The c# runs ONLY on the server side.. so to get your checkbox and textcontent to the server, you will have to put a submit button and POST your form. And if you do that, you probably won't need to call c# from anywhere in your cshtml !

Comment: The OP is asking about calling a C# method from within JavaScript, which is not possible.

Comment: No, the title sais **cshtml** not javascript.

Comment: @Goodies: but his code has a function declared `function submitClick()  { ... }`.  That's Javascript.  You can refer to `@somethingFromC#` in the Javascript, but the Javascript can't call `C#Namespace.ClassName.StaticFunction()` (or any other C# function).  If you want your click to do something on the server, you will have to do a POST (or other HTTP verb) back to the server

Comment: In that case you can still call C# to return valid Javascript *code* (not with above code hehe) We don't know what is intended here. I use above kind of @-calls a lot to *generate* the Javascript. You can leave a string and even assign a string (s='@Class1.generator() But I'm afraid we'll have to start out with the basics. Question is (title) "can I call c# from cshtml". Answer is yes :)

Comment: Then you're not calling C# from JavaScript, but JavaScript code that is outputted from a C# function. Semantics matter here.

Comment: Ah you're right actually. I will put a note in my answer

Comment: I'm gonna try it out later. It is bit more complicated than I thought, but I think I'm starting to understand how it works. Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: @Ruhtra: Read up on REST (and/or AJAX).  They loosely describe ways that your client-side code can call back into your controller